# Duplicate value of useRef current value after switching between tabs in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If i switch between Transfer to Beneficiary and All Beneficiary tab the Select options get duplicated but if i change the second useEffect hook dependency to **allBeneficiary.current** instead of **beneficiaries** presently there, Select options doesnt duplicate, but the options are not rendered on the first render until I switch to All Beneficiary tab and back to Transfer Beneficiary

[image: The values get duplicated after navigating to All beneficiaries and back to Transfer Beneficiaries]

Below is the Transfer to Beneficiary code

```js
// Hooks and Contexts
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { TransferPointsContext } from "../../../../../context/TransferPoints";
import { LoaderContext } from "../../../../../context/Loading";

// Components
import TransferSummary from "../../../../common/modals/TransferSummary";
import Loading from "../../../../features/Loader/Loading";

// UI
import swal from "sweetalert";
import toastr from "toastr";
import Select from "react-select";
import "./css/transfer-points.css";
import { nanoid }from 'nanoid'

function TransferPoints() {

  const [showTransferSummary, setShowTransferSummary] = useState(false);
  const [transferSummaryData, setTransferSummaryData] = useState(false);
  const [showBeneficiaryDataPage, setShowBeneficiaryDataPage] = useState(false);
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const [ options, setOptions ] = useState([])

  const {
    verifyCardNumber,
    verifyCardState,
    getBeneficiaryList,
    beneficiaries, //list of beneficiaries from API
    hideBeneficiaryDataPage,
    setInputs,
    inputs,
  } = useContext(TransferPointsContext);
  const { loading } = useContext(LoaderContext);

  toastr.options.progressBar = true;
  toastr.options = {
    toastClass: "alert",
    iconClasses: {
      error: "alert-error",
      info: "alert-info",
      success: "alert-success",
      warning: "alert-warning",
    },
  };



  const allBeneficiaries = useRef([]);
  

  useEffect(() => {
    getBeneficiaryList();
  }, [allBeneficiaries]);


  useEffect(() => {
    if (beneficiaries.data !== null) {
      if (
        beneficiaries.data.status === 0 &&
        beneficiaries.data.success === false
      ) {
        toastr.error("Failed to fetch user beneficiaries!", "error", {
          iconClass: "toast-error",
        });
        console.log("beneficiaries", beneficiaries.data);
      } else  if (
          beneficiaries.data.status === 1 &&
          beneficiaries.data.success === true
        ) {

        console.log('All beneficiary ', allBeneficiaries.current)

        beneficiaries.data.data.forEach((beneficiary) => {
          console.log('For each ', beneficiary)

          allBeneficiaries.current.unshift({
            value: beneficiary.membership_number,
            label: `${beneficiary.first_name} ${beneficiary.last_name == null ? '' : beneficiary.last_name}`,
          });
        });
        console.log('LENGTH ', allBeneficiaries.current.length) 
      }
    }
  }, [beneficiaries]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hideBeneficiaryDataPage) {
      setShowBeneficiaryDataPage(false);
    }
  }, [hideBeneficiaryDataPage]);

  const beneficiaryData = useRef({});


  useEffect(() => {
    if (verifyCardState.data !== null) {
      if (
        verifyCardState.data.status === 1 &&
        verifyCardState.data.success === true
      ) {
        setShowBeneficiaryDataPage(true);

        beneficiaryData.current = {
          name: `${verifyCardState.data.data.first_name} ${verifyCardState.data.data.last_name == null ? '' : verifyCardState.data.data.last_name}`,
        };

        toastr.success("Membership Id Validated!", "Success", {
          iconClass: "toast-success",
        });
        return;
      }

      if (
        verifyCardState.data.status === 0 &&
        verifyCardState.data.success === false
      ) {
        if (verifyCardState.data.message && !verifyCardState.data.data) {
          toastr.error(verifyCardState.data.message, "Validation failed!", {
            iconClass: "toast-error",
          });

          setShowBeneficiaryDataPage(false);
          return;
        }

        setShowBeneficiaryDataPage(false);
        const errorMessages = verifyCardState.data.data;

        for (const error in errorMessages) {
          toastr.error(errorMessages[error], "Validation Error!", {
            iconClass: "toast-error",
          });
        }
        return;
      }
    }
  }, [verifyCardState]);

  const handleSearchInput = (event) => {
    const card_number = event.value;
    setInputs((inputs) => ({
      ...inputs,
      card_number,
    }));
    verifyCardNumber(card_number);
  };

  const proceedToTransfer = () => {
    const amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
    if (amount.trim().length === 0) {
      swal({
        title: "Oops!",
        text: `Amount field cannot be empty`,
        icon: "error",
        button: "Ok",
      });
      return;
    }

    setShowTransferSummary(!showTransferSummary);
    setTransferSummaryData({
      amount,
      name: beneficiaryData.current.name,
      membership_id: inputs.card_number,
      save_beneficiary: (beneficiaryData.current.save_beneficiary == 1) ? 1 : 0,
    });
  };

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    event.persist();
    setInputs((inputs) => ({
      ...inputs,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    }));
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.persist();
    setChecked(event.target.checked);

    const save_beneficiary = event.target.checked === true ? 1 : 0;
    beneficiaryData.current.save_beneficiary = save_beneficiary;
  };


  console.log('LENGTH ', allBeneficiaries.current) 

  // console.log('current beneficiaries ', (allBeneficiaries.current) )
  // console.log('CHECKED ', beneficiaryData.current.save_beneficiary )

  // let id = nanoid()

  return (
    <div>
      {/* {loading ? <Loading /> : ""} */}
      <form action="#">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12">
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="acc-email">Select Beneficiary </label>
              <Select
                onChange={handleSearchInput}
                className="basic-single"
                classNamePrefix="select"
                isClearable="true"
                isSearchable="true"
                name="beneficiary_card_number"
                defaultValue="Select"
                options={allBeneficiaries.current} //THIS RETURNS DUPLICATED VALUE ON NAVIGATING TO ALL BENEFICIARIES AND BACK
              />
            </div>
            <h6 class="mt-3 heading-border border-0">OR</h6>

            <div className="row align-items-center justify-content-between">
              <div className="col-md-8">
                <label htmlFor="card_number">Enter Membership Id</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="card_number"
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  value={inputs.card_number}
                />
              </div>

              <div className=" col-4 " style={{marginTop: '30px', paddingLeft: '10px', textAlign: 'end',}}>   
                <button
                  onClick={() => verifyCardNumber(inputs.card_number)}
                  type="button"
                  className="btn-lg  btn btn-primary"
                >
                  Validate Id
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          {showBeneficiaryDataPage === true ? (
            <div className="col-sm-12">
              <h6 class="mt-3 heading-border border-0"></h6>
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-6">
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="acc-name">Name</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control"
                      id="acc-name"
                      required
                      disabled
                      name="acc-name"
                      value={beneficiaryData.current.name}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div className="col-md-6">
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="acc-lastname">Membership Id</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control"
                      id="acc-lastname"
                      required
                      disabled
                      name="acc-lastname"
                      value={inputs.card_number}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12">
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="acc-lastname">Amount</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control"
                      id="amount"
                      required
                      name="amount"
                      onChange={handleInputChange}
                      value={inputs.amount}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-check">
                <input
                  class="form-check-input"
                  type="checkbox"
                  checked={checked}
                  name="save_beneficiary"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <span className="ml-3 font-weight-bold terms-condition">
                  Save Beneficiary
                </span>
              </div>

              <div className="mb-2"></div>

              <div className="form-footer">
                <div className="col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <button
                    onClick={() => proceedToTransfer()}
                    type="button"
                    className="btn-lg w-50 btn btn-primary"
                  >
                    Proceed
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
        </div>
      </form>
      {showTransferSummary === true ? (
        <TransferSummary data={transferSummaryData}  setShowTransferSummary={setShowTransferSummary} setShowBeneficiaryDataPage={setShowBeneficiaryDataPage}/>
      ) : (
        ""
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default React.memo(TransferPoints);
```

This is the code for All Beneficiaries

```js
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./css/transfer-points.css";
import { TransferPointsContext } from "../../../../../context/TransferPoints";
import Loading from "../../../../features/Loader/Loading";
import swal from "sweetalert";
import { LoaderContext } from "../../../../../context/Loading";
import toastr from "toastr";
import axios from 'axios'
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';


function ShowAllBeneficiariesPage() {

  const [ data, setData ] = useState([])
  const {
    getBeneficiaryList,
    beneficiaries,
    removeBeneficiary,
    state,
  } = useContext(TransferPointsContext);
  const { loading } = useContext(LoaderContext);

  toastr.options.progressBar = true;
  toastr.options = {
    toastClass: "alert",
    iconClasses: {
      error: "alert-error",
      info: "alert-info",
      success: "alert-success",
      warning: "alert-warning",
    },
  };

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    swal({
      title: "Are you sure you want to remove beneficiary?",
      text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
      icon: "warning",
      buttons: ["Cancel", "Proceed!"],
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
      cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result === true) {
        removeBeneficiary(id);
        console.log('ID OF RECEIVER ', id)
        const newBeneficiary = data.filter(add => add.id !== id)
        setData(newBeneficiary)
        toastr.success("Beneficiary Removed !", "Success", {
          iconClass: "toast-success",
        });
      }
    });
  };


  const fetchData = () => {
    axios.get(`user/beneficiaries`)
    .then( res => setData(res.data.data ))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {/* {loading ? <Loading /> : ""} */}
      { data.length === 0 ? 
      (
        <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>No beneficiaries found</div>
      ) 
        : 
      (
        <div className="col-sm-12">
          {data.map((item) => {
            console.log('Beneficiary Data ', data)
            return (
              <p className="mb-1 p-4 beneficiary-list">
                {item.first_name} {item.last_name} - {item.membership_number}
                <i
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                  onClick={() => handleDelete(item.id)}
                  class="float-right fas fa-trash"
                ></i>{" "}
              </p>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
    
  );
}

export default (ShowAllBeneficiariesPage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `allBeneficiaries` (or any other ref object) as a dependency for a hook won't help you at all. The ref object's identity will never change over the lifetime of a component.

If you want to run an effect/... when the value boxed within the `allBeneficiaries` ref changes, the dependency will need to be `allBeneficiaries.current`.

Beside that, there's no good reason to use a ref for `allBeneficiaries`. Since it affects rendering, you will want to save it as a state atom (`useState`).

Comment: Thanks for coming through i got it right.

Answer (score 2):

I can't completely fix your issue, because I'd need more context and time, but I've found some issues on your code.

1. Never ever ever, have something in your render code that has a reference to a `useRef` variable. When a `useRef` value changes, react will completely ignore it and will not update your component. Use `setState` for those.
2. It sounds like your `allBeneficiaries` instead of being a ref or a state it's just derived state: It looks like it's a derived value from `beneficiaries`. In this case, you don't need to use any hook, just declare it as a `const` (e.g. `const allBeneficiaries = getBeneficiaries(beneficiaries)`). If you have performance issues, then consider using `useMemo`, but it should not be needed.
3. Never use a `useRef` as a dependency value in a `useEffect` - Same thing, react doesn't care about ref values, so you'll have unexpected behaviour there (effects retriggering when it shouldn't, effects not triggering when they should)
4. Try to avoid `useEffect` as much as posible. It should only be used for specific cases, such as fetching something from a server or manipulating the dom. For the rest of them, it's just problematic, best avoided.

Comment: Thanks a lot. olivarra1. I just got a role as a front end dev and i have to fix this issue the former dev caused. I will try everything out and revert.

Comment: Solved man, used use state to get the beneficiaries then create an array of object to track individual data and passed the array to the select option and everything works fine.